# Session.Abandon doesn't fire Session_End in Load Balancer Environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, load-balancing

I am using Session.Abandon to clear the session data, which internally will fire session_end to end the session. It is working fine in my local machine, but it fails(doesn't fire session_end) when I test it in production environment. We are using Load Balancer in Production environment so I suspect that may be the reason that session_End event doesn't fire, though session data is getting cleared. Session State is in InProc Mode only.

Edit-

To correct - We have two web sites which are hosted through IIS in One Single Machine and Load balancer takes care of navigating the request to IIS. Both web sites share same cookie.We are trying to set some value in Session_Start of second site based on cookie value. It works fine for the first time when user redirected from first site to second site, but second time redirection we get the session null. I am pretty sure that it can only happen if session_start is not called second time which basically means that when  first time redirect we call session.abandon which doesn't fire session_end and henceforth for all the subsequent request session_Start doesn't get fire.

Comment: You are storing session data local to each machine and yet expect the sessions to be functional in a load balanced scenario?

Comment: @KirkWoll - I don't get your comment as I am new to Load Balancing, but to make it clear we have on web site which is hosted in single box and we are using Load Balancer. I am able to create session data in login page and able to use the session data in different pages. Only problem is that somehow it doesn't fire Session_end.

Comment: question in ambiguous, you are using Load balancer and site hosted in one box????

Comment: @Punit, is your load balancer using sticky sessions?  Also, why are you using a load balancer if you only have one node behind it?

Comment: @eka -Ops team has configured Load Balancer in one machine which routes the request to the related server. We have different server for Web & Windows Service. I can find out more details about how it has been configured...

Comment: @KirkWoll - Good Question... but I don't know why are we using Load Balancer for one node... I need to check whether we are using sticky session... can sticky session create issues for session.abandon?

Comment: @Punit, well, it can create an issue if you are abandoning on what node and the session exists on another.  On the other hand, if you only have one node, I'd expect this all to be moot.

Comment: @KirkWoll - Sorry, I corrected my question. We do use two nodes.

Comment: @Punit, so long story short is if you are using inproc session state and not using sticky sessions (on the load balancer) then you have a problem.  I'd recommend fixing that problem before futher investigating your original question.

Comment: @KirkWoll - Sure I will check it, but I can see that I am able to create the session and used the same session across different page requests.

Answer (score 0):

When your sites are behind load balancer, InProc mode will not work for sites depending on session. Take the session to either SQLServer or State Server and provide a machine config value. Refer these links.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms178586.aspx
http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2007/11/22/ASPNET-load-balancing-and-ASPNET-state-server-(aspnet_state).aspx
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604

Comment: InProc Mode in Load balancer will work after reading through diff articles. I am able to store value into session and used it in different pages.

Comment: If you are using sticky session then InProc mode will work, otherwise there is a chance of successive requests to hit different server during roundtrips. Again that purely depends on how your LB is configured to handle the load round-robin / active requests / sticky etc...